# How to get recently dialled numbers

Tags: android, phone-call

I am working on an application, where i need to fetch 5 recently dialled numbers. I am able to sort the numbers in descending order, so as the recently dialled numbers comes first. I am using the following code to fetch the recent numbers.

```
dialledCall = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialledCall);

              String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
              Cursor mCallCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                      null,
                      CallLog.Calls.TYPE 
                      ,null,
                      strOrder);
              mCallCursor.moveToFirst();
              do {
                  if( i >5 )
                      break;
                  mobileNumber =   mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
              number += mobileNumber + "\n";

              i++;
              }
              while (mCallCursor.moveToNext());
         dialledCall.setText(number);
```

With this, i am able to sort the numbers in recent order and also i have just fetched last 5 numbers. But the query returns all the numbers, i mean Dialled, Missed and Received as well. But here i want just the dialled numbers.

I know there is something to do with `CallLog.Calls.TYPE` in the above query.

I have tried passing null value, but it returns all the numbers.

I also have tried `CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE` in place of it, but it gives error that int value is not permitted, it should be a string value.

Any suggestions on how to replace the above code, so as to only get the dialled calls.

**Note-** I have already looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480569/1626878, but it does not provide a solution to only fetch the dialled numbers.

Comment: ,as you have already raised this question and my query is quiet similar with you,and I want to fetch last 20 dialed calls,and got your code quiet interesting...so could you give any idea for getting last 20 dialed calls.

Comment: yep, for sure. here i have fetched last 5 calls using the if condition in the do while loop. i have used if(i>5) to fetch last 5 calls, you can use if(i>20), then break the loop. hope it helps. tell me whether it helped or not.

Comment: sure....and thanks for this valuable comment.

Comment: One more thing is that as you said this piece of code is fetching dialled,received & missed calls,but even I just want the info about dialled calls.Any inputs on this context...

Comment: hmm, I have solved the issue, let me post the answer.

Comment: @user1645434 : I have posted the answer. let me know if solved your issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, so I am posting it for future visitors.

```
    String mobileNumber="";
    int i = 1;
    String number = "";
    TextView dialledCall;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            dialledCall = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialledCall);

    //              String[] strFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,         android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION     };
                  String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
                  Cursor mCallCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                          null,
                          CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE
                          ,null,
                          strOrder);
                  mCallCursor.moveToFirst();
                  do {
                      if( i >5 )
                          break;
                      mobileNumber =   mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                  number += mobileNumber + "\n";

                  i++;
                  }
                  while (mCallCursor.moveToNext());
             dialledCall.setText(number);
        }
```

Here `CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE` in the query separates out the dialled calls.

Comment: silly to ask this(newbie to android),....will  I have to call these piece of code in a function of my Activity class?

Comment: yes you can use it directly in your activity's oncreate. I have edited my answer. and keep in mind, never hesitate to ask. _If you will never ask, you will never know_.

Comment: couple of things;1> how do you initialize dialledCalls?//getting error in this line; 2>what's the layout of dialledCall.xml(as you are calling R.id.dialledCall)

Comment: @user1645434 : why dont you post a new question with these problems and share its link here. It will easy to solve it then.

Comment: because I'm blocked to ask a Question (: :( ,just you tell me the according dialledCall layout,I'll solve it.

Comment: I have created a **TextView** with id **dialledCall** in the **main** layout and initialized it here.

Comment: thanks,...and mobile number & number-you have call these variables in this class.. am I right ?

Comment: edited my answer. check the declaration of variables. I have declared them in the same class.

Comment: I have run the apk file,it showing blank page :(,in xml I just add a TestView like **<TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialledCall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" /> **

Comment: where have you tested the apk.? in emulator or phone.? are there any dialled calls in the phone.? first dial some calls in the phone, then test the apk.

Comment: I have test the apk in Anadrd device,I'st I'm getting exception like NullPointer,then add this exception in the code,still getting no values,one more is that first I have mention in my (activity's)corresponding xml file,later on you told you have called the TestView in main.xml,so I did...but yet no output I get :(

Comment: 1. add this attribute to your **TextView** in the **main** file **android:text="Hello"**. Now checkc whether it is displaying Hello on the screen or not. 2. Also check that whether there are any dialled calls in your phone.

Comment: I have post question,and here's the link, you can take a look of it,here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873735/unable-to-get-recently-dialled-numbers

Comment: Hi Sahil,it's working...thanks a lot for your benevolent support;Just one think I'll ask:In the CallLog it's printing last message + dialled numbers,How to identify only DialledCalls.

Comment: It should be printing only the dialled calls not the sent messages. I have tested it.

Comment: But in my device callLog has the list of outgoing message and outgoing call,then how to differentiate the outgoing call from message ?

Comment: Hi Sahil,I have editted my post,if you have time,could you take a look of it..//

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CallLog class to get at this information (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html).

You're interested in the getLastOutgoingCall method, which returns the last phone number called.

Check the call logs. You can easily access this. Do something like,

Define,
public `Cursor mCallCursor`;

Then define the fields you want to obtain from the call log,

```
public static final String[] STR_FIELDS = {
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER
        };
```

Set the order,
public static final String STR_ORDER = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

Call the cursor.

```
mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            STR_FIELDS,
            null,
            null,
            STR_ORDER);
```

Comment: You should look at the question again. I just want to sort the cursor data on the basis of dialled numbers, which are recently dialled. I dont want different fields of the number and i a done with STR_ORDER in descending order.